# How to install Nextcloud on Ubuntu 16.04 using snap?

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, snappy

So I've installed snapd on Raspberry Pi 3 with fresh Ubuntu 16.04 installed on it. After doing :

```
 $ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

And rebooting i've installed snapd using

```
$ sudo apt install snapd
```

After that I tried to install nextcloud using snap but go this error during intstallation process:

```
 $ sudo snap install nextcloud

- Setup snap "core" (893) security profiles (no state entry for key)
- Setup snap "nextcloud" (863) security profiles (cannot setup apparmor     for snap "nextcloud": cannot load apparmor profile "snap.nextcloud.apache":     
enter code herecannot load apparmor profile: exit status 1
    apparmor_parser output:
    Cache read/write disabled: interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor  compatibility patch.)
    Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?Use --subdomainfs to override.)
    - Setup snap "nextcloud" (863) security profiles (cannot load apparmor profile "snap.nextcloud.apache": cannot load apparmor profile: exit status 1
    apparmor_parser output:
    Cache read/write disabled: interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor compatibility patch.)Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted? Use --subdomainfs to override.)
```

Result of snap chages:

```
$ sudo snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn                 Ready                 Summary
1    Error   2017-02-07T20:21:12Z  2017-02-07T20:27:46Z  Install "nextcloud" snap
```

I also reinstalled snapd and even tried to reset snapd with [this script](https://github.com/zyga/devtools/blob/master/reset-state) but no success.

I also tried to install ubuntu-core packages using:

```
$ sudo apt install ubuntu-core-*
```

Didn't help me either.

Has anybody succeeded with installing nextcloud using snap on Ubuntu 16.04?

P.S I'm using Ubuntu Server Standard 16.04 image from [this source](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/).

Comment: Good first question, but it would be helpful to know how you are installing nextcloud. Could you please add that?

Comment: Simply with sudo snap install nextcloud. But I've never used snapd before, so maybe i missed something while installing snapd (installed on fresh Ubuntu with sudo apt install snapd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the log, this is not official Ubuntu. It seems that the kernel in your image is different, and is missing the AppArmor components needed by snaps. Please report this to ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org.

You might consider looking at the rpi images of [Ubuntu Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3), which is completely snap-based.